# Android Activity Tab View Pager Immersive error

Tags: android-fragments, android

I'm trying to take advantage of the translucent Status and Nav bars in API 19, and running into some layout issues.

Given that I start with a clean project using ADT, I set it up to use a Blank Activity, and set the navigation to Action Bar Tab with a View Pager.

As soon as I enable the transparent Status and Nav bars with the following style:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

The actual fragment I'm trying to view under the ViewPager gets moved to the top of the screen, and appears under the Status bar (note the top half of a "1").

[image: FragmentCutoff]

Well, after reading [some info on compensating for the ActionBar height](http://mindofaandroiddev.wordpress.com/2013/12/28/making-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-transparent-with-a-listview-on-android-4-4-kitkat/) (see Part 4 for the `setInsets()`) I've gotten the fragment to display below the ActionBar. Problem being, I'm still not displaying **below the ViewPager as well.** The second screenshot is from an app I'm working on, and has the SystemBarTint library working to compensate for the ActionBar height.

[image: FragmentCutoff2]

Additionally, I can't measure the ViewPager during the `onViewCreated()` of the Fragment to add that to the inset, since the ViewPager hasn't yet been created (at least for the first section. In testing though, each other fragment is still giving me issues).

So the ways I've thought of to solve this are:

1. Create the Fragments after loading -- certainly not ideal, I don't want to have something flash on the screen after activity load.
2. Inflate the view in `onCreate()` of the activity, then make a second pass to recompute the inset/padding needed for the fragments.

Are either of these good solutions, am I missing something?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/...
refer that link very useful

Comment: For reference, the link above is broken. Try [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/).
Also, I can create and work with the ViewPager and Tabs just fine. The problem is that when I enable the transparent status, the ActionBar goes into overlay mode, and I have no programmatic way of computing (that I'm aware of) how much to pad the fragment containing my content.

Comment: Guessing this question will go unanswered. For the record, I'm working around this by using a NavDrawer instead of the Tabs and ViewPager. Would've preferred not to use a different layout style, but it's working, so I'll take it.